# Available WiFi network not showing..but I have enable Notebook WiFi

Tags: wireless

Since this morning I am facing trouble with WiFi 
When I started my Notebook it's give error like the package cache is currepeted.now I have checked with all command it's all showing true ..I have WiFi enabled it's showing enable d but available WiFi networks is not showing and when I try go through network settings it's all available network is showing out of range..there no sign of available networks.so plz help me out from this.

Comment: Hello and welcome to askubunut;  In order to maximise your chances to get your question solved, I advise you to review your post by adding more specfic information: what hardware / software (esp. ubuntu version) are you using,...  Also mention if toher devices see WiFi connections.  For more info on how to ask a good question, please review the help page: https://askubuntu.com/help

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your network module from the Linux kernel. To find your wireless adapter type 
`lspci | grep "Wireless"`
Make sure to get the network adapters  name
 Then remove the module by typing

```
modprobe -r [network adapter]
```

Then add it back by typing

```
modprobe [network adapter]
```